# Where to put custom xml file? can't create

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have this custom xml file. I would parse it later.
The problem is where to put it. I used eclipse adt.
I created a new folder in the resources. I named it "xml".
After that i tried to create a XML file in the folder. 
Right clicked the xml folder>new>android xml file
Then the window pops. I change the folder to res/xml but when I clicked the finish button nothing happens. Can you help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: `/res/xml` is the folder where you usually put your SharedPreferences layout file(s). I discourage you to put your "other" files there - better use the `assets` or the `res/raw` folders.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean all your projects.
2. Update your ADT.

Answer (score 0):

If its not the layout file, place it in asset folder

```
 <AppName>/assets/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create android xml then that should be created in layout folder and extends any of android layout or controls.

For creating custom xml file, right click on res/xml folder --> new --> file and enter your filename.xml

Don't forget to add extention .xml

Comment: when i change the folder to res/xml it wont let me create